# Ubuntu can't mount my pendrive

Tags: usb

I am pretty new to AskUbuntu and with Ubuntu itself.
My pendrive can't be mounted.

I open a terminal and type this command:

```
sudo tail -c 0 -f /var/log/syslog
```

and the result is...

```
Feb  2 18:16:57 nala-desktop kernel: [ 8079.295959] usb 2-1.6: new high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci    
Feb  2 18:16:57 nala-desktop kernel: [ 8079.432209] usb 2-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=1666    
Feb  2 18:16:57 nala-desktop kernel: [ 8079.432217] usb 2-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3    
Feb  2 18:16:57 nala-desktop kernel: [ 8079.432221] usb 2-1.6: Product: DataTraveler 3.0    
Feb  2 18:16:57 nala-desktop kernel: [ 8079.432225] usb 2-1.6: Manufacturer: Kingston    
Feb  2 18:16:57 nala-desktop kernel: [ 8079.432229] usb 2-1.6: SerialNumber: 60A44C3D7ECDBE4029740102    
Feb  2 18:16:57 nala-desktop kernel: [ 8079.432711] usb-storage 2-1.6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected    
Feb  2 18:16:57 nala-desktop kernel: [ 8079.432881] scsi host17: usb-storage 2-1.6:1.0    
Feb  2 18:16:57 nala-desktop mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 14: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6"    
Feb  2 18:16:57 nala-desktop mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 14 was not an MTP device    
Feb  2 18:16:58 nala-desktop kernel: [ 8080.495288] scsi 17:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kingston DataTraveler 3.0 PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 6    
Feb  2 18:16:58 nala-desktop kernel: [ 8080.496166] sd 17:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0    Feb  2 18:16:58 nala-desktop kernel: [ 8080.520328] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk    
Feb  2 18:17:00 nala-desktop gnome-session[1519]: (gnome-software:1842): Gs-WARNING **: failed to get updates: no results to show    
Feb  2 18:17:01 nala-desktop colord-sane: io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1    
Feb  2 18:17:01 nala-desktop CRON[3995]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Anyone can help me with this?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: It looks like your usb key is detected. Did it work before on ubuntu?
Can you show the output of "lsblk"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply ShadowMitia
The output of "lsblk" is 

`NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 298,1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   4,9G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda2   8:2    0     1G  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0    50G  0 part 
└─sda6   8:6    0 242,2G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 149,1G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0  39,1G  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0     1K  0 part 
├─sdb5   8:21   0  58,6G  0 part 
└─sdb6   8:22   0  51,4G  0 part`